# How to extract a pattern in a timeseries by using several columns in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pattern-matching

I have a DataFrame containing different measures from different Timestamp Looking like this:

```
data=np.array([["2019-08-08 08:29", 29.9, 4., 1.],["2019-08-08 08:30", 30.1, 4., 1.],["2019-08-08 08:31", 30.1, 0., 0.], ["2019-08-08 08:32", 27.2, 1., 0.], ["2019-08-08 08:33", 15.0, 2., 0.], ["2019-08-08 08:34", 15.1, 2., 0.], ["2019-08-08 08:35", 19.1, 2., 1.], ["2019-08-08 08:36", 26.7, 2., 2.], ["2019-08-08 08:37", 30.0, 2., 3.], ["2019-08-08 08:38", 30.1, 2., 3.], ["2019-08-08 08:39", 29.9, 0., 0.], ["2019-08-08 08:40", 25.1, 1., 0.], ["2019-08-08 08:41", 23.4, 2., 0.], ["2019-08-08 08:42", 15.1, 3., 0.]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data[:, 1:4], index=data[:, 0], columns=["A", "B", "C"], dtype='float64')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print(df.to_string())
                        A    B    C
2019-08-08 08:29:00  29.9  4.0  1.0
2019-08-08 08:30:00  30.1  4.0  1.0
2019-08-08 08:31:00  30.1  0.0  0.0
2019-08-08 08:32:00  27.2  1.0  0.0
2019-08-08 08:33:00  15.0  2.0  0.0
2019-08-08 08:34:00  15.1  2.0  0.0
2019-08-08 08:35:00  19.1  2.0  1.0
2019-08-08 08:36:00  26.7  2.0  2.0
2019-08-08 08:37:00  30.0  2.0  3.0
2019-08-08 08:38:00  30.1  2.0  3.0
2019-08-08 08:39:00  29.9  0.0  0.0
2019-08-08 08:40:00  25.1  1.0  0.0
2019-08-08 08:41:00  23.4  2.0  0.0
2019-08-08 08:42:00  15.1  3.0  0.0
```

I would like to find all the paterns in the Data defined as follows:

- Start of the pattern: Column B reaches the value 0.
- End of the pattern: Column C reaches a maximum.

Here is a plot of the values with the pattern represented by the horizontal bars:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(df.index, df.A)
plt.axvline(x="2019-08-08 08:31", color="red")
plt.axvline(x="2019-08-08 08:37", color='red')
plt.axvline(x="2019-08-08 08:39", color='green')
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(df.index, df.B)
plt.plot(df.index, df.C)
plt.axvline(x="2019-08-08 08:31", color="red")
plt.axvline(x="2019-08-08 08:37", color='red')
plt.axvline(x="2019-08-08 08:39", color='green')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of the data and the pattern]

The red bars lock one pattern and the green one is the beginning of a new pattern.

To identify the patterns I first created two columns finding the beginning and the ending of a pattern:

```
df["New_pattern"] = (df['B'] == 0) & (df['B'].shift(1) != 0)
df["End_pattern"] = (df['C'] > df['C'].shift(1)) & (df['C'] == df['C'].shift(-1))

print(df.New_pattern.loc[df.New_pattern == True].to_string())
2019-08-08 08:31:00    True
2019-08-08 08:39:00    True

print(df.End_pattern.loc[df.End_pattern == True].to_string())
2019-08-08 08:37:00    True
```

So this is giving me the good result to find the beginning and the ending of a pattern in this sample Data. Though in my real Data, I have twice more end of pattern than begining of pattern. I think this is because I have several flat zone in the Data for the column C between two new patterns but I didn't find any evidence for now.

Also you shoud know that whenever the measurement B reaches 0, the measurement C also reaches 0 and otherwise these values cannot decrease, so I know there is a maximum between two new patterns.

I have two questions:

1. How to find the end pattern between two new patterns timestamp instead of using the wole dataframe ? It would be calculated by putting true to the timestamp of the first time the maximum value is reached between two new patterns.
2. How can I extract the patterns of the data by using the columns New_pattern and End_pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem but I don't know if it is the most efficient one.

I create a DataFrame that stores the timestamp of the beginning of new patterns and I -1 shift in an other column.

```
df_pattern = df.New_pattern.loc[df.New_pattern == True].reset_index()["index"].rename("New_pattern").to_frame()
df_pattern["Next_new"] = df_pattern.shift(-1)
```

I calculate the idxmax of the C column of the first dataframe by selecting all the rows between the timestamp of the two columns of my new dataframe for each rows of this new dataframe. This gives me the end of each pattern.

```
def getEndPattern(row):
    if not pd.isnull(row[0]) and not pd.isnull(row[1]):
        return df.C.loc[row[0]:row[1]].idxmax()
    else:
        return np.nan

df_pattern["End_pattern"] = df_pattern.apply(lambda row: getEndPattern(row), axis=1)
print(df_pattern.to_string())
          New_pattern            Next_new         End_pattern
0 2019-08-08 08:31:00 2019-08-08 08:39:00 2019-08-08 08:37:00
1 2019-08-08 08:39:00                 NaT                 NaT
```

Then I create a column in my first DataFrame filled by nan to store the number of the current number. I iter over the rows of the DataFrame containing the pattern timestamps to select the rows between those timestamps and I put the right number of pattern:

```
df["number_pattern"] = np.nan
for index, row in df_pattern.iterrows():
    if not pd.isnull(row[1]):
        df["number_pattern"].loc[row[0]:row[2]] = index
print(df.to_string())

                        A    B    C  New_pattern  number_pattern
2019-08-08 08:29:00  29.9  4.0  1.0        False             NaN
2019-08-08 08:30:00  30.1  4.0  1.0        False             NaN
2019-08-08 08:31:00  30.1  0.0  0.0         True             0.0
2019-08-08 08:32:00  27.2  1.0  0.0        False             0.0
2019-08-08 08:33:00  15.0  2.0  0.0        False             0.0
2019-08-08 08:34:00  15.1  2.0  0.0        False             0.0
2019-08-08 08:35:00  19.1  2.0  1.0        False             0.0
2019-08-08 08:36:00  26.7  2.0  2.0        False             0.0
2019-08-08 08:37:00  30.0  2.0  3.0        False             0.0
2019-08-08 08:38:00  30.1  2.0  3.0        False             NaN
2019-08-08 08:39:00  29.9  0.0  0.0         True             NaN
2019-08-08 08:40:00  25.1  1.0  0.0        False             NaN
2019-08-08 08:41:00  23.4  2.0  0.0        False             NaN
2019-08-08 08:42:00  15.1  3.0  0.0        False             NaN
2019-08-08 08:42:00  15.1  3.0  0.0        False             NaN
2019-08-08 08:42:00  18.1  3.0  1.0        False             NaN
2019-08-08 08:42:00  15.1  3.0  1.0        False             NaN
```

Now when I will want to do some analysis, I will group by the number of the pattern or use the DataFrame with the timestamps.

This is my solution, but I would gladly welcome other suggestions using Pandas or Python tricks that would maybe make it easier, quicker or just different to see the different way to do that.